# Autocomplete/suggest search for a social chat app with Nodejs Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to come with the most practical search possible for an auto suggest search bar like the one on instagrams (it's able to match regex of strangers). So let's say I have a million user with their own unique handle. I want to be able to do the suggest search as the user is typing on the front-end. For ex if the current strings of the user type field are 'dav' its will match any unique handles in the entire Mongodb for that regex. I know mongo does support find field with regex but how do I limit the maximum of results for efficiency. I cannot find an answer on this for Mongoose. Say the user is search for 'dave' and there's like 3k results that match 'dave' but it will stop at search at the first 10 and return those result. So the user gonna have to be more specific with the unique handle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using limit() (and additionally skip() if you want to use pagination)

```
db.users.find(...).limit(10)
```

This will return the first 10 results.